# Real open source project that uses Structuremap?

Tags: structuremap

I want to learn structuremap and how to arrange/structure my DI code, Are there any open source project that uses StructureMap that I can look at for guidance?

Answer (score 2):

[Code Camp Server](http://code.google.com/p/codecampserver/)

- [some StructureMap configuration](http://code.google.com/p/codecampserver/source/browse/trunk/src/DependencyResolution/DependencyRegistry.cs)

Answer (score 0):

[AtomSite](http://code.google.com/p/atomsite/) - ASP.NET MVC blogging application.